# Parse.com Cloud Code - 503 Bad Gateway Periodically

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to use Custom Webhooks with Parse.com. I created the sample app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.query.message + "\n");
});

app.listen();
```

When I first try to reach the endpoint, it gives me the expected result:

```
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:TestApp slabko$ curl "http://testappsa.parseapp.com/test?message=hello"
hello
```

But, when I try it again I get this:

```
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:TestApp slabko$ curl "http://testappsa.parseapp.com/test?message=hello"
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

When I continue trying, sometimes I get the expected result, but then other times I get a 503.

The Parse status page claims "All Systems Operational".

Here is an example of what I'm seeing: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1526868/parse502.mov

What is wrong with my hook? Why is it unreliable?

Comment: I know this post is told now but I'm seeing this occasionally making requests out to Parse.  @Slabko I am curious how you might have resolved this issue or if you did at all?

Comment: The issue just vanished on the next day, however I still see it periodically, but not really often and it doesn't last long. In simple words - I haven't solved it.

Comment: Ha!  Amazing.  Thanks for the update anyways.